# d3 mouse argument with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse, d3.js

I am trying to get the mouse coordinates of a div using d3, and I have working code that looks like

```
var mouse = d3.mouse(document.getElementById('container'));
```

When I try to use a jquery selector though to do something like

```
var mouse = d3.mouse($('#container'));
```

this fails

I also tried

```
var mouse = d3.mouse(d3.select('#container'));
```

which also fails.

Is there a more compact way to rewrite my first statement using jquery/d3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the jQuery selector will return a jQuery object.  You need to grab the base DOM element using [0]:

```
var mouse = d3.mouse($('#container')[0]);
```

I hope this helps!